# jscrollpane not showing scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have setup a simple test of scrollpane js, but can't get it to show the scrollbar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/scrollpane.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scrollpane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.scroll_pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>



 <style>
 .scroll_pane {
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        font-size:12px;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    </style>
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/v7gyX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem are not one but some mini errors.
In your jsfiddle you don't call your scrollpane in document ready and you have to put the text inside a tag p for example.
 I think that your css must be edit and I have make a new jsfiddle with a complete css

this works fine:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
<p>
text 
</p>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7gyX/2/)

P.S. I have changed the name of the class but it wasn't that the problem

Comment: Thanks...adding the p tags inside the div fixed it....document ready not necessary http://jsfiddle.net/v7gyX/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this one it works perfectly.

Just go to jsfilddle link mention below.

```
<div class="scroll_pane">
<p>

your html text 
</p>
</div>
```

remaing every thing is same

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7gyX/1/)